# Green Droid: How To Set Background Picture For GDActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, background, image, greendroid

Can anyone produce clear example of how to set up background picture in `GDActivity` within its constructor method (or somehow else) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive pointed out how to do this.

GDActivity use special layout structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<view
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="greendroid.widget.ActionBarHost"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/gd_action_bar_host">

    <view
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            class="greendroid.widget.ActionBar"
            android:id="@+id/gd_action_bar"
            />

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/gd_action_bar_content_view"/>
</view>
```

So when we follow logic, we should be setting background picture for content view frame, right ?

But that is not true.

This is not working:

```
Drawable mBackgroundDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash);
getContentView().setBackgroundDrawable(mBackgroundDrawable);
```

We must use standard access to a window.

```
Drawable mBackgroundDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.splash);
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(mBackgroundDrawable);
```

Any corrections would be appreciated.